# Can you give me a hand with my Update trigger? It looks like it should work

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, triggers

This is what I have. It looks like MS's example adn I can't figure out why it's not running. I get an Invaild column name 'PlanID' error on this line:

`WHERE gm.PlanId = i.[PlandID]`

I was under the impression INSERTED would contain the same fields as the Plan table. Maybe I'm way off - this is my first trigger!

PlanID is the primary key in the Plan table and is a foreign key to Measures. I'm basically looking to check when a row in Plan's Status field is updated and then update the Status field in Measures.

```
CREATE TRIGGER utr_Plan_Cascade_Status
   ON  [dbo].[Plan]
   for UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF(UPDATE([Status]))
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.Measures
            SET [Status]= i.[Status]
        FROM dbo.Measures m, INSERTED i, DELETED d
            WHERE m.PlanId = i.[PlandID]

    END

END
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: By specifying three comma-separated tables in your `FROM` clause - but only **one** join condition between `m` and `i` - you're basically creating a cartesian product matching each row from `m`/`i` with each row in `d` - thus updating way too many rows... see SQLMenace's answer - use proper **ANSI** JOIN syntax with `INNER JOIN` which forces you to properly specify join conditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using old style [joins](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/sql-advent-2011-day-15)?

You also don't need the deleted table at all.

This should work for you

```
 UPDATE m
            SET m.[Status]= i.[Status]
        FROM dbo.Measures m
        JOIN INSERTED i ON m.PlanId = i.[PlandID]
```

Just as a FYI..`IF(UPDATE([Status]))`  will fire if you do the following

```
Update Table set Status = Status
```

perhaps you want to add `where m.Status <> i.Status` to your WHERE clause

Also keep in mind that if that column is nullable you need to account for that in this where clause

Comment: Is there any kind of performance difference between old style and what you wrote or just ease of reading?

Comment: No performance difference but it is very easy to create a `cartesian product` with that old style syntax by mistake

Comment: The new syntax is ansi standard. I would test for performance your self; it depends if the query optimiser produces the same plan for all queries (which I expect it would) view the execution plan to see for your self.

Comment: @RussellHart both are ANSI ANSI SQL-92 (new style) syntax and the ANSI-SQL-89 (old style) syntax.

Comment: Very interesting. I'll try to keep these things in mind as I work through my SQL noob tendencies. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You miss spelled PlanID as PlandID.

Comment: Dammit.That's embarrassing.  =)

Answer (score 1):

first, you need to use proper `JOIN` syntax and you had a misspelled word

```
CREATE TRIGGER utr_Plan_Cascade_Status
   ON  [dbo].[Plan]
   for UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF(UPDATE([Status]))
    BEGIN
        UPDATE m
            SET m.[Status]= i.[Status]
        FROM dbo.Measures m
        INNER JOIN INSERTED i
            WHERE m.PlanId = i.[PlanID]

    END

END
```